# trouble with running ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I trying to run for app on server and log file give me an error

```
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

and in log file

> [2014-03-12T09:50:22.614788 #1647]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for
>   84.38.185.44 at 2014-03-12 09:50:22 +0000
>       F, [2014-03-12T09:50:22.771502 #1647] FATAL -- : 
>       ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
>         actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>         actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>         railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
>         railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
>         activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
>         activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in`tagged'
>         activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
>         railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
>         actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
>         rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
>         rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>         activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in`call'
>         rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
>         railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call'
>         railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
>         unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in`process_client'
>         unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:660:in `worker_loop'
>         unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:527:in`spawn_missing_workers'
>         unicorn (4.7.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:153:in `start'
>         unicorn (4.7.0) bin/unicorn:126:in`'
>         /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
>         /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in`'
>         /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `eval'
>         /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   '

that can i do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the root route is not defined. Open your route.rb ad check if there's something like this:

```
root :to => "controller#index"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to add the following line (`posts` for example)?

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'posts#index'
```